# iOS: Is it allowed to use libIOKit.dylib

Tags: iphone, ios, dylib

Is it "app store safe" to use this lib?

Answer (score 1):

No. libIOKit.dylib (also known as IOKit), is a non-documented, low-level interface that would allow developers to change device settings and behavior.  Apple will reject any app that tries to use it.

More info about IOKit: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/IOKit.framework